# What is the unit for the Spring actuator http.server.requests statistic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have service implemented with `spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RELEASE`. I have enabled actuator metrics for it, however I cannot understand what units are the metrics presented in. Specifically, I am interested in the `http.server.requests`.

A sample output of the endpoint is:

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.049653001
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.040696019
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now (Spring-Boot:2.0.0 and Micrometer:1.0.2) the unfortunate answer is: It depends.

The `/actuator/metrics` endpoint is backed by the currently active `MeterRegistry` implementation in your application. This implementation defines the base-unit of time in which the timed information is presented.
E.g. if you got `micrometer-registry-prometheus` in your classpath only, the `/acturor/metrics` endpoint will serve timing information in [seconds](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/v1.0.2/implementations/micrometer-registry-prometheus/src/main/java/io/micrometer/prometheus/PrometheusMeterRegistry.java#L331). If you got e.g. `micromter-registry-graphite`, the endpoint will serve in [milliseconds](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/v1.0.2/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/dropwizard/DropwizardMeterRegistry.java#L150) (It's backed by `DropwizardMeterRegistry`.). If you got no "special" `MeterRegistry` implementation attracted, the `SimpleMeterRegistry` will become the backing registry and will [serve seconds](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/v1.0.2/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/simple/SimpleMeterRegistry.java#L157).

To make things a little worse, if you got multiple `MeterRegistry` implementations aboard, the first implementation registered with the `CompositeMeterRegistry` will be chosen as the backing implementation which serves the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint.

Disclaimer: The information has been collected from/with [jkschneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510017/jkschneider), the maintainer of `Micrometer`.

Comment: Looks like I got all three just by using `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. Would have been nice to have a `unit` field for each metric.